# Mount network share folder in Vagrant

Tags: windows, vagrant, directory, share

I want to mount (connect) folder which is shared in corporate network to my Vagrant machine.

What I have:

- Folder which consists installation files (.exe) and shared in corporate network;
- Windows based (8.1) Vagrant machine.

I tried `NFS`, `Rsync`, `SMB` options - nothing works.

Here is part of Vagrant file which I have:

```
  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "V:\Dev\Ort Sys\Releases\Daily Build\Rel 2015\x64", "\share", type: "nfs"
```

Please, help me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved this problem. All you need to do is to do what's in Vagrant comment above

> The first argument is the path on the host to the actual folder. The
>   second argument is the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the
>   optional third argument is a set of non-required options.

I bypassed this by using PowerShell script and this command:

```
 New-PSDrive –Name “B” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “\\name\of\the\folder\which\I need to mount” –Persist
```